# Does the set of all finite subsets of positive integers form a group under set intersection?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let A be a set of all finite subsets of positive integers. I have proved closure and associativity under intersection. I am kind of confused about existence of identity. Originally, I was thinking that the set of all positive integers also lives in A and when any set M in A intersects with that set, we will get M back. However, I am not sure if the set of all positive integers even lives in A cause it is not finite, is it?

Any help would be great.

Comment: No, the set of all positive integers is not finite

Comment: But I still think that identity exists. For any element in A let’s say {1,2,3,4,.......,z}, there also exists another set with one more element. But where does this stop though? Cause identity is unique. So confused.

Comment: Yes $\emptyset$ $\in$ $A$. Its cardinality is $0$, hence it is a finite set.

Comment: If $I$ is identity, $I \cap \{n\} = \{n\}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So, $n \in I$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $I$ is not finite.

Comment: When you say {n}, do you mean {1,2,3,....n}?

Comment: The sets $\{1\},\{2\},...,\{n\},...$ are subsets of $A$.

Comment: But the same arguments works with $\{1,...,n\}$

Comment: I think they just mean the singleton set containing the integer $n$. The statement that $I \cap \{1,\ldots,n\}  = \{1,\ldots, n\}$ is true for all $n$ so $\{1,\ldots , n\}\subset I$ for all $n$ which gives the same conclusion

Comment: A set with a binary operation that is associative and closed but not necessarily with identity and inverses is a [semigroup](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already given yourself the answer.

Proof by contradiction: Assume there is an identity element $I\in A$ with the usual property. Since $I$ is a finite subset of integers there exists a maximum element $n=\max I$. Now consider the set $B=I \cup \{n+1\}$. $B$ is finite, thus an element of $A,$ but $B\cap I\neq B$. Hence, $I$ is not the identity element.

Comment: Unless finite subsets exclude the empty set, you cannot assume the existence of a maximum element $n$ of $I$.  (To be sure, it doesn't take much work to fix this.)

Comment: @Briang Tung you are completely right!

Answer (score 3):

Another proof by contradiction which doesn't worry about infinity:

If $A$ does form a group then there is some identity $I$ and some $\emptyset^{-1}$ with $\emptyset\cap\emptyset^{-1}=I$, but $\emptyset\cap\emptyset^{-1}=\emptyset$ so $I=\emptyset$. For a contradiction take any nonempty $J\in A$ (say $J=\{1\}$), then $J=J\cap I=J\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$.